# Templated constexpr variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

I want to confirm that this code is legal (or not legal?) C++17.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N> inline constexpr float MyConst;

template<> inline constexpr float MyConst<1> = 1.1f;
template<> inline constexpr float MyConst<2> = 2.2f;

int main ()
{
    std::cout << MyConst<1> << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I don't get errors (and get correct output) if compiled by **g++** and **MSVC**,

but **Intel** and **clang** give an error:

```
test.cpp(3): error: missing initializer for constexpr variable
  template<int N> inline constexpr float MyConst;
                         ^
```

Compiled with `-std=c++17` (`/std:c++17` for MSVC).

Tried with latest compilers on godbolt as well as on my local machine.

Comment: gcc compile without issue, so maybe it's a clang bug?

Comment: then it looks like a bug in all other compilers that i tried

Comment: MSVC accepts your code.

Comment: @AdrianMole Good to know - I am on Linux

Comment: @user2052436 linux me too and no prob with gcc. On coliru works with g++ and fail with clang too. You should try on godbolt

Comment: @rustyx So is it ill-formed and a not-really-resolved [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92576) of g++?

Comment: @rustix Dupe of my issue, indeed. So this is illegal and SFINAE does not apply to templated consts? Or is SFINAE irrelevant here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `constexpr` variable must be immediately initialised.  Hence the template for `MyConst` needs an initialiser/definition.  GCC is going against spec by not requiring a definiton at first occurance.  If you use a non-specialised form of the variable e.g. `MyConst<3>` [you will get a similar error from GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/f4KrjsMqK):

```cpp
<source>: In instantiation of 'constexpr const float MyConst<3>':
<source>:10:18:   required from here
<source>:3:40: error: uninitialized 'const MyConst<3>' [-fpermissive]
    3 | template<int N> inline constexpr float MyConst;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In instantiation of 'constexpr const float MyConst<3>':
<source>:10:18:   required from here
<source>:3:40: error: uninitialized 'const MyConst<3>' [-fpermissive]
    3 | template<int N> inline constexpr float MyConst;
      |
```

This can be fixed by provided a initial definition for MyConst, e.g.

```cpp
// Use a "sensible default"
template<int N> inline constexpr float MyConst(0.0f);

// Provide a more general definition
template<int N> inline constexpr float MyConst = N*1.1f;
```

For the relevant part of the standard, see [dcl.constexpr paragraph 1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr).

> The *constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the **definition** of a variable or variable template* or the declaration of a function or function template. The consteval specifier shall be applied only to the declaration of a function or function template. A function or static data member declared with the constexpr or consteval specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable. If any declaration of a function or function template has a constexpr or consteval specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the same specifier.

Comment: I understand that the `constexpr` needs to be initialized. My expectation was that with templated `constexpr` it would work in SFINAE fashion, i.e. as long as I am only using `MyConst<1>` and `MyConst<2>`, and not, say `MyConst<3>`, it would be ok.

Comment: So was mine, but the `constexpr`-ness of the initial declaration prevents that.  You can make the original non-`constexpr` and make the template specialisations `constexpr` and it will behave more intuitively.  https://godbolt.org/z/1MbYKbGva

Comment: Thanks. That's a good solution.

Another solution I see is to have a `template<int N> struct` with `static inline constexpr MyConst` inside; `struct` is specialized for required values of `N`. This will cause compile-time failure for wrong N-s. This approach will give me what I initially intended to have, no caveats, right?

Comment: If you try that, GCC finally notices the lack of definition for a constexpr object and fails to compile any example.  https://godbolt.org/z/M67d5fnqd

Comment: I meant this https://godbolt.org/z/a9GdYzEsc

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that the `constexpr` needs to be initialized.

C++14 standard, from section 7.5.1 paragraph 9,

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the
> object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be
> initialized.

Then:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N> inline constexpr float MyConst = 0.0f;

template<> inline constexpr float MyConst<1> = 1.1f;
template<> inline constexpr float MyConst<2> = 2.2f;

int main ()
{
    std::cout << MyConst<1> << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

works well both for g++ and clang.

Comment: I understand "that the constexpr needs to be initialized".

My expectation was that with templated `constexpr` it would work in SFINAE fashion, i.e. as long as I am only using `MyConst<1>` and `MyConst<2>`, and not, say `MyConst<3>`, it would be ok.

Comment: As user202436 notices: The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the **definition** of a variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or function template. And constexpr definition means initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

This is [DR 1712](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1712).

One the one hand, `constexpr` variables must be initialized, on the other a `template` isn't a "thing" until it's instantiated, and hence does not necessarily need an initial value until then.

Unfortunately the standard doesn't currently exempt `constexpr` variable templates from the requirement of having an initial value. So technically the code is ill-formed.

The corresponding GCC issue is [#68012](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68012), questioning whether or not a diagnostic is required.